# how to set values passing one page to another page?

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

Hi this is am using xaml page,i want to navigate with selected item.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="NotchsList11"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="left" Width="Auto"  Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate> 
         <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"  Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="NotchsList11_SelectionChanged">
              <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                       </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="152" Height="90"  Stretch="Fill"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                   </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My xaml.cs page code is given below

```
private void NotchsList11_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Notch selectedItemData = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Notch;
        if(selectedItemData != null)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Test.xaml?parameter={0}",selectedItemData.articleid), UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

if i select any one item i cant navigate to other page,because i got error selectedItemData is null.so any one can help me?

Comment: What's the itemsource of the listbox? selectedItemData is null because the casting to Notch probably didn't work.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line in the function and type in Immediate Window "(sender as ListBox).SelectedItem" without quotes. If it is not null, then you can see what kind of item is that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to pull from the sender object.  Just pull what you need directly from the list object if in fact the code believes that an item is truly selected and not null.

You just need to change your SelectionChanged method to look like this:

```
    private void NotchsList11_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NotchsList11.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Test.xaml?parameter={0}",
                (NotchsList11.SelectedItem as Notch).articleid), UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Here's an example:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-8-JumpStart-1b7c34e3/sourcecode?fileId=72994&pathId=1694015380

Comment: Hi i changed this thing but no change in my output.

Comment: It's likely that you have an issue with some code somewhere else in your application that you are not displaying for us to see.  If you share more code and data, we may be able to figure out the full extent of your issue.

Comment: Hi if u want all my code please see this link and help me.i think u can able to help me.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544201/how-to-set-page-navigation-from-listbox-to-another-page/15652950?noredirect=1#15652950]

Comment: Hi @Rob.Kachmar did u see my code?you have any idea for resolving this issue?am waiting for your replay.

Answer (score 0):

A.

```
        private void NotchsList11_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Notch selectedItemData  = NotchsList11.SelectedItem as Notch;
        if (selectedItemData != null)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Test.xaml?parameter={0}",selectedItemData.articleid), UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

B. Or you can use whole SelectedItemData object as data context

```
private void NotchsList11_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Notch selectedItemData  = NotchsList11.SelectedItem as Notch;
        if (selectedItemData != null)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Test.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            FrameworkElement root = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
            root.DataContext = selectedItemData;
        }
    }
```

Remarks: In Test page you can use (Notch)DataContext to reference instance of the Class so you can use Image data as ((Notch)DataContext).Image

C. Or, this way:

```
        private void NotchsList11_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(((Notch)e.AddedItems[0]).articleid, UriKind.Relative));

            ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Remarks: Notch  is class that you Bind as ItemSource to ListBox

Best regards
Spaso

Comment: Hi thanks to replay. i hope your answer.but how can i get selected value and show on related article to details page?can help me?