# How to set page navigation with data from listbox?

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Hi am using xaml file given below.I have list from list-box with item source. I want page navigation with selected data to other page.

```
<ListBox x:Name="NotchsList11"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
       Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="left" Width="720"  Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="ControlsPanel"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Height="215"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel Background="#eb2427" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="34" FontWeight="Bold"  FontStyle="Normal" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Text="{Binding name}"
                               />               
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
                          <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectionChanged="NotchsList11_SelectionChanged"></ListBox>
               </StackPanel>
             </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>         
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My xaml.cs code

```
private void NotchsList11_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Notch selectedItemData  = NotchsList11.SelectedItem as Notch;
    if (selectedItemData != null)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Test.xaml?parameter={0}",selectedItemData.articleid), UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

I tried this code but selected item data getting null.am struggling long time in this issue so please any one give me solution.

Comment: please show us the code of how you are binding the data...

Comment: Please refer this links have my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544201/how-to-set-page-navigation-from-listbox-to-another-page/15652950?noredirect=1#15652950

Answer (score 0):

In your code SelectionChanged="NotchsList11_SelectionChanged" is present in Images list instead of NotchsList11 List. Please see Modified code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="NotchsList11"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  SelectionChanged="NotchsList11_SelectionChanged"
   Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="left" Width="720"  Grid.RowSpan="2">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="ControlsPanel"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Height="215"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel Background="#eb2427" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="34" FontWeight="Bold"  FontStyle="Normal" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        Text="{Binding name}"
                           />               
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
                      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
           </StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>         
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi thanks to your replay already i tried this thing, if i do like this selectionChanged is not firing

Comment: Now i tried this thing i cant set because i am getting error The Member HitVisible is not recognized or is not accessible

Comment: See the updated answer changed ListBox to ItemsControl and its not HitVisible its IsHitTestVisible

Comment: Please can u review once again your update answer?there is only closing list box i cant get clearly.sorry i was typed wrongly HitTestVisible.HitTestVisible is also i cant set

Comment: Hi @ Mahantesh i tried your update answer but i got only image url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27553/discussion-between-mahantesh-and-user123)