# how to navigate from a listbox in windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am building an application for Windows Phone 7 where in a ListBox I am showing data from the web service.
The WebService contains the following data:
News Title, News Description, Date Start and image path.
In the list box I am showing News Title, Date Start and image path.
Now on clicking an item from the list box I want to navigate to another page which should show all the three details along with news description.

My xaml is:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
           <!-- SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged"-->
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Button.Content>
                       <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="80" Width="400">
                           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" Height="80" Width="120"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                 <!-- <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>-->
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                                     </StackPanel>
                                  </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The .cs file is:

```
 public News()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     KejriwalService.aapSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
     client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
     client.getarvindNewsAsync();

     progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
 }

 void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     string result = e.Result.ToString();
     List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

     progressName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

     foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
     {
         Newss data = new Newss();

         data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;
         //data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
         data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
         data.image_path = location.Element("image_path").Value;
         data.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri( @"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/"+data.image_path, UriKind.Absolute));

         listData.Add(data);
     }

     listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;
}
```

Now in a new page say newsdetails.xaml i want to navigate from this page and show the complete details.
Please help.
I am stuck in this as I am new in this domain.
I am almost done with my app if this is done.

```
 private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;
        var item = listBox1.SelectedItem as Newss;
        if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("SelectedObject"))
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["SelectedObject"] = item;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsDetails.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Comment: As per ur question u can take listbox_selectionChanged event,and there u can take switch case .For particular selected index u can navigate by navigation service to particular page.As per i understood ur question I would suggest this.

Comment: @djFox... can you please suggest first how do i navigate to a new page say newsdetails.xaml onclicking a listbox item based on the code i wrote. can u please write the code for that?

Comment: where is ur selection_change Event code

Comment: @djFox... please see the code i posted just now

Comment: @djFox... Please see the code i wrote for navigation. Its not navigating

Comment: we have to write some codes in on navigated to event also.Actually am working in another work.Tomorrow will provide u codes.But u can refer this article --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544201/how-to-set-page-navigation-from-listbox-to-another-page

Comment: @djFox... Please help me on my issue if you are free today

Answer (score 0):

Define static global variables in that page where your listbox selection change event is:

```
public static string title;
public static string news_description;
```

On listbox selection change assign these variables:

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;
        var item = listBox1.SelectedItem as Newss;
        if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("SelectedObject"))
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["SelectedObject"] = item;
            title=item.News_Title;
            news_description=item.News_Description;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsDetails.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

And in your navigation NewsDetails.cs page Access these items like this:

```
string Title=YourPageName.title;//
string Description=YourPageName.news_description;
```

show these values as you want